# Flutter : Can't detect if app destroy (AppLifecycleState.detached)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an app with fingerprint security, But I don't know how logic to do this.

Meanwhile i have logic like this, Save when user exit the app + duration token (example : 07.40 + 30 second) then if user comeback again , compare :

```
 @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
  setState(() => _appLifecycleState = state);
  print(state);

 if (_appLifecycleState == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {// 07.40 30.00 > 07.40 29.00
  if(DateExit.isAfter(DateTime.now())){
   print("still available token")
   return;
  }else{ // 07.40 30.00 > 07.40 31.00
   print("expiry token , Goto Confirm Fingerprint Screen")
   final actionBox = repository.changeExpiryToken(
            userModelHive: UserModelHive()
              ..id = model.id
              ..giverName = model.giverName
              ..pinCode = model.pinCode
              ..fingerPrint = model.fingerPrint
              ..darkMode = model.darkMode
              ..expiryToken = !model.expiryToken
              ..durationToken = model.durationToken,
          );
          return actionBox;
  }
 }else{
  dateExit = DateTime.now().add(Duration(seconds: 5));
  print('Another Lifecycle');
 }
}
```

Everything is fine I can detect if the user only swaps to another app or open the recent app, I can change `tokenExpiry` status if `DateExit.isAfter(DateTime.now())`. 
But the problem is, I can't detect if the user destroys the App although I already handle in my logic.

I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Zeffry Reynando did you found any solution for this? I also want to handle my app on app destroy. Please share if you found any solution of it.

Answer (score 0):

`didChangeAppLifecycleState` hasn't existed any states for checking that app has already been starting. You can see here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/AppLifecycleState-class.html. In this case, you should use `initState` to check

Answer (score -1):

I was also getting same issue. So now I found one solution to detect if the app destroyed.
In flutter we have one method name - *dispose()*
In my case the *dispose()* method was not getting called on app destroy. So I just update my *dispose()* method. See the below code.

```
  @mustCallSuper
  @protected
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);

    print('dispose called.............');
    super.dispose();
  }
```

I hope it will solve your problem too.